# Why do certain non-Latin characters show up as empty boxes, and how can I fix them?

Tags: special-chars

See this screenshot for an example (view the original page [here](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.01.0133:book%3D1:card%3D1)):

[image: Perseus on Android]

As you can see, most of the missing characters have some sort of accent/breathing mark on them. This occurs in all applications that I've tried (such as opening a text file in Dropbox), not just in the browser.

Does anyone know what is going on, and how I can fix it? I am running Android 2.1 on a Samsung Fascinate (not rooted).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your standard charset problem.  The file's in UTF-16 and the app only supports UTF-8, or you don't have the font for the "weird" characters, etc.  More than likely there is nothing you can do; Android internationalization support is pretty bad and most apps don't even try.

Comment: How can I install a font for the "weird" characters? It seems strange that the default Android browser wouldn't have internationalization support, even if third party apps don't.

Comment: I don't know how Android handles fonts or if you can install them.  You might try temporarily changing your system language.